# Logging for Talend job running within spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, talend

We have talend-jobs triggered within Spring-boot application. Is there any way to configure the output of talend-jobs to the application log files? 
One workaround we find is to write logs directly to an external file (filePath passed as context-param). But wanted to find if there is a better way to configure this seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I guess your concerns might be on what might have happened to the triggered Jobs.

### Logging

With Respect to Logging for Talend, You could configure using Log4j,
https://help.talend.com/reader/5DC~TBhDsBie5JTXyVLW4g/QSGCZJKXo~uhKvZDq1DxUg

### Monitoring

Regarding the Status of the Job Executed, you could get the execution details retrieved using REST Call(Talend Metaservlet API).

**getTaskExecutionStatus**
https://help.talend.com/reader/oYf9gKhmYrkWCiSua4qLeg/SLiAyHyDTjuznLR_F~MiQQ

By Modifying the Existing Talend Job,You could also design a like a feedback loop, ie Trigger a REST Call back to your application. With the details of Execution from Talend Job.